# How can I remove a sub array from a big array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array, I want to remove dynamically:

```
Array (
    [fields] => ID
    [number] => 0
    [meta_query] => Array (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array (
            [key] => role
            [value] => Array (
                [0] => subscriber
                [1] => author
                [2] => custom-one
                [3] => custom-two
            )
            [compare] => IN
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [key] => country
            [value] => United States
            [compare] => =
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [key] => near_by_place
            [value] => someplace
            [compare] => LIKE
        )
    )
    [order] => ASC
    [meta_key] => last_name
    [orderby] => meta_value
)
```

I want to remove the following (where `[key] => near_by_place`):

```
[2] => Array (
    [key] => near_by_place
    [value] => someplace
    [compare] => LIKE
)
```

This can be in any index , right now its on index 2 but it can be on 1,2,3 or 4 or any.

Comment: Why don't you just use _unset()_?

Comment: what is the search criteria to remove?

Comment: How will you know which one to remove? Will the key/values always be the same in the one you want to remove?

Comment: sorry I @FirstOne , I just changed the values only.

Comment: @saurabh , I want to remove where [key] => near_by_place

Comment: You want to filter your subArray `meta_query`. There you also want to make sure you only apply your condition to arrays and not to your "normal" values like `relation`.

Comment: One more thing .
[2] => Array (
    [key] => near_by_place
    [value] => someplace
    [compare] => LIKE
)     always will be on last index of meta_query array

Comment: Yeah exactly @Rizier123

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array is called $values:

`$values = array_slice($values, 2, 1);`

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: But indexing is not fixed